# Why isn't the CSS file I'm hosting on Github not getting recognized by Mailchimp's embed signup code?

Tags: css, mailchimp

I swapped out the default .css file Mailchimp provides for their sign up form's embed code with one I copy pasted over to Github, but it doesn't seem to be getting used.

Any idea why?

The default .css file Mailchimp provides is at: [cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-061523.css](https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-061523.css)

The .css file I want to use instead is at: [raw.githubusercontent.com/jaywuzer/HipHopOnDaPullUp/main/MailChimpEmbed.css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaywuzer/HipHopOnDaPullUp/main/MailChimpEmbed.css)

```
<div id="mc_embed_shell">
      <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaywuzer/HipHopOnDaPullUp/main/MailChimpEmbed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <style type="text/css">


        /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
           We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>


<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="https://hiphopondapullup.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=72af4cf5a706e12fa4f5180bc&amp;id=139e61457f&amp;f_id=00f97ae4f0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

            <div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></label><input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required="" value=""></div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear foot">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    <div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
        /* real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups */
        <input type="text" name="b_72af4cf5a706e12fa4f5180bc_139e61457f" tabindex="-1" value="">
    </div>
        <div class="optionalParent">
            <div class="clear foot">
                <input type="submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" value="Subscribe" >

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[3]='ADDRESS';ftypes[3]='address';fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';fnames[5]='BIRTHDAY';ftypes[5]='birthday';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script></div>
```

I've tried swapping the URLs for the css stylesheet back and forth between my Github one and Mailchimp's default one. For some reason only when I use Mailchimp's URL does the stylesheet get picked up.

I've tried duplicating Mailchimp's css code exactly to Github in case this was caused by some of the small changes I made to the code. Same problem, the Github one will not get used.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, `github.com` is not sending any `Content-type` header at all. Most browsers, mail clients etc. will not load a stylesheet if the server providing it does not send the `Content-type: text/css` header.

As a solution, you could look into using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) to host the css file, then you probably can use it the way you want. CSS files from `raw.githubusercontent.com` will not work, as it seems.